# array and command in column' s definition of table

Tags: tables, macros, arrays

to develop a specific class, I would like to define columns in a table by a macro definition. Like in this MWE

```
\def\titi{c|c|c}

\begin{tabular}{\titi}
a& b&c\\
a& b&c\\
a& b&c\\
\end{tabular}
```

That works good. Except we use the array package. I obtains `` Illegal pream-token (\titi): `c' used ``

I have try with `\expandafter\tabular{\titi}` but no change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\expandafter\tabular{\titi}
```

expands the `{` which does nothing, you would want

```
\expandafter\tabular\expandafter{\titi}
```

Or better

```
 \newcolumntype\titi{ccc}
 \begin{tabular}{\titi}
```

Comment: indeed, I have forgotten the `{` ... the `\newcolumntype` is indeed better.